# Jenkins Pipeline Template - Approaches

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I came across a blog post for defining pipeline templates [here](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/10/02/pipeline-templates-with-shared-libraries/). What is the difference between the below 2 declarations -

```
vars/myDeliveryPipeline.groovy
def call(Map pipelineParams) {

    pipeline {
        agent any
        stages {
            stage('checkout git') {
                steps {
                    git branch: pipelineParams.branch, credentialsId: 'GitCredentials', url: pipelineParams.scmUrl
                }
            }

            stage('build') {
                steps {
                    sh 'mvn clean package -DskipTests=true'
                }
            }

            stage ('test') {
                steps {
                    parallel (
                        "unit tests": { sh 'mvn test' },
                        "integration tests": { sh 'mvn integration-test' }
                    )
                }
            }

            stage('deploy developmentServer'){
                steps {
                    deploy(pipelineParams.developmentServer, pipelineParams.serverPort)
                }
            }

            stage('deploy staging'){
                steps {
                    deploy(pipelineParams.stagingServer, pipelineParams.serverPort)
                }
            }

            stage('deploy production'){
                steps {
                    deploy(pipelineParams.productionServer, pipelineParams.serverPort)
                }
            }
        }
        post {
            failure {
                mail to: pipelineParams.email, subject: 'Pipeline failed', body: "${env.BUILD_URL}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2nd Approach

```
vars/myDeliveryPipeline.groovy
def call(body) {
    // evaluate the body block, and collect configuration into the object
    def pipelineParams= [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = pipelineParams
    body()

    pipeline {
        // our complete declarative pipeline can go in here
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The essential difference here is in the usage for the passing of the Pipeline parameters to the method containing the pipeline during invocation.

For the first example, you will be passing a `Map` directly via `myDeliveryPipeline(params)`:

```
myDeliveryPipeline(branch: 'master',
                   scmUrl: 'ssh://git@myScmServer.com/repos/myRepo.git',
                   email: 'team@example.com', serverPort: '8080',
                   serverPort: '8080',
                   developmentServer: 'dev-myproject.mycompany.com',
                   stagingServer: 'staging-myproject.mycompany.com',
                   productionServer: 'production-myproject.mycompany.com')
```

For the second example, you will be passing a `Map` via a closure that resembles a DSL via `myDeliveryPipeline { params }`:

```
myDeliveryPipeline {
  branch            = 'master'
  scmUrl            = 'ssh://git@myScmServer.com/repos/myRepo.git'
  email             = 'team@example.com'
  serverPort        = '8080'
  developmentServer = 'dev-myproject.mycompany.com'
  stagingServer     = 'staging-myproject.mycompany.com'
  productionServer  = 'production-myproject.mycompany.com'
}
```

Other than argument usage, the methods are identical. It will come down to your preference.

Comment: Thanks @Matt Schuchard.

Comment: In addition to Matt's answer, I found this paragraph in the [Jenkins documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-a-more-structured-dsl):

"There is also a 'builder pattern' trick using Groovy’s Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST, which permits Jenkinsfile to look slightly more like a configuration file than a program, but this is more complex and error-prone and is not recommended."

I'm not sure why exactly the 2nd approach might be more complex but I thought this might be worth sharable.

Comment: @RobertStrauch The second approach was the formerly recommended usage and it did have issues. A modified version of the first approach is now the recommended usage. For example, the first usage allows passing the `env` and `params` map directly as arguments, whereas the second usage does not allow this (unresolved bug).

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks for that info. Didn't know that.